# Нужно спарсить сайт на Python

Tags: python, html, css, парсер, информация

https://mediakit.iportal.ru/our-team
Нужно получить Имя, почту город и должность
как это можно сделать
пробовал единственным мне знакомым способом через тэги, совсем не выходит
Подскажите что нибуль

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А ручками не быстрее будет?

Comment: Подскажу. Используйте email как якорь для определения соседних элементов

Answer (score 1):

Вообще данный сайт является динамическим, т.е. элементы подгружаются при прокрутке. Поэтому вы не можете вытянуть информацию при запросе. Советую изучить библиотеку Selenium для такого вопроса.